# Does spring boot Data JPA guarantees the data order in findAll()

Tags: spring, database, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Is repository.findAll() return records in particular order? if yes, what will the order of the records.
also does it gurantees the same order always(Database is same)?

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot Data JPA does not guarantee any specific order when using the `findAll()` method.

The order of the results may vary based on the underlying database implementation.

If you want the records to be returned in the specific order, then you can use, for example:

```
repository.findAll(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "column_name"));
```